# Avoiding boilerplate creating new immutable instances in C++

Tags: c++, immutability

I'm working with persistent data structures.
I'll have a complex class that I need to create a new instance but with one or more fields with different values.

```
struct Data {
  int field1; int field2; int field3; // etc.
public:
  Data withField2(int newField2) {
      return { field1, newField2, field3 };
  }
};

int main()
{
  Data d = { 1, 2, 3 };
  std::cout << d.field2 << std::endl;
  Data newD = d.withField2(4);
  std::cout << newD.field2 << std::endl;
}
```

Worst case, I can create a bunch of `withField1(newField1Value)` methods as above but there will be enough fields such that it would get really messy.
Also, I might want new values for multiple fields, so then there could be many more.

So, is there some magic way of saying

```
Data newData = data.with(field1Name = newField1, field2Name = newField2)
```

or something similar?

Comment: No, I'm afraid there's no magic in C++. Looks to me like, perhaps, the class needs to be redesigned. Instead of a bunch of individual `int` fields, put them all in a single array, and this now becomes a much easier task.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern . Could give you something like `DataBuilder(d).withField1(1).withField2(42).build()`. Pretty common in Java.

Comment: If you want to avoid boilerplate, don't make the data private.  Keep it public, make a copy of the object, make the changes.

Comment: C++ just doesn't support functional programming very well. Use something like Haskell instead.

Comment: you could have the underlying fields be represented by an array and then your `withField` method would take an index and a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that, but you can do something interesting with pointers to data members:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>

struct Data {
  int field1; int field2; int field3; // etc.

  template<int Data::*M>
  Data withField(int value) {
    Data cpy = *this;
    cpy.*M = value;
    return cpy;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Data d = { 1, 2, 3 };
  std::cout << d.field2 << std::endl;
  Data newD = d.withField<&Data::field2>(4);
  std::cout << newD.field2 << std::endl;
}
```

This way you don't have to write all the `withField` member methods at least.

With a bit of machinery and metaprogramming, maybe you could also define a method that changes a bunch of data fields all at once.

Of course, this works fine as long as your fields are all of type `int`.
Otherwise, you need more than one method or something like this:

```
template<typename T, T Data::*M>
Data withField(T value) {
  Data cpy = *this;
  cpy.*M = value;
  return cpy;
}
```

That has to be invoked as:

```
Data newD = d.withField<int, &Data::field2>(4);
```

Comment: Um, how exactly does this protect the members from modification?

Comment: @SebastianRedl Actually I copied the OP's example that doesn't protect the members at all. I thought he was fine with it, wasn't he?

Comment: Seems to me he thought they were private. But maybe not.

Comment: @SebastianRedl In the OP's example they are not. Default visibility of structs is public. Otherwise he wouldn't have been able to initialize them as aggregate, as he did in the example. ;-)

Comment: Exactly what I was asking for. Absolutely brilliant. Thank you!

Comment: It's straightforward to extend to multiple fields by just adding templates:
`template<typename T, T Data::*M, typename T2, T2 Data::*M2>` and `cpy.*M2 = value2;`

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that you are reinventing `std::tuple`. But you didn't reinvent `std::get<N>`.

Your implementation uses names, and to the compiler they're utterly arbitrary. There's no guarantee the field names occur in numerical order without gasps.